# Getting Facebook Friends Picture Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi i have this script and im having a problem getting facebook friends profile picture. I always get

"Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(Array) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/my1date1/public_html/judeapps/fans/img.php on line 31"

This is my index.php CODE.

```
        <?php
session_start();
require_once 'src/facebook.php';
      set_time_limit ( 120 );


$app_id = "661337633905378";
$app_secret = "958db3fad7cffbb395ae3314e069d743";
$redirect_uri = "http://apps.facebook.com/ivalentines_daysss/";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));
@$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
if($code)
{
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

   $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
  $user_country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];

 $country = $user_country;
switch ($country)
 {

case 'my': //malaysia
$message = 'Find out your Super Fans here ===> http://on.fb.me/iFacebookPeekers';
break;
case 'fi': //finland
$message = 'Selvit채 oma Super Fans t채ss채 ===> http://on.fb.me/iFacebookPeekers';
break;
default:
$message = 'Find out  your Super Fans here ===> http://on.fb.me/iFacebookPeekers';
}

   //friends list
   $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=name,picture');

   //array of final friends
  $final_friends = array();

    for($x=0;count($final_friends)<=9;$x++)
    {
    $rand_friend = rand(0,count($friends["data"])-1);
  if(!in_array($friends["data"][$rand_friend],$final_friends))
  {
  $final_friends[] = $friends["data"][$rand_friend];

  }
 }

    $image_path = 'img/'.$user_id.'.png'; //GD generated image
require_once 'img.php';


$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);


$photo_details = array('tags'=> $tags, 'message'=> $message, 'image' => '@' . realpath($image_path) );
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

unlink($image_path);

 //for page redirection
$webpage = "https://www.facebook.com/craigintimidator.mcarthu"; //redirects user after uploading picture
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
location.href = '$webpage';
</script>";

}
else
{
$url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$app_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&scope=read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos";
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $url . "'</script>");
}

    ?>
```

And this is my img.php CODE

```
     <?php


     $dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/back.jpg');

       //set font properties
        $im = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 20);
      $name_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 8,8,8);
    $view_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 8,8,8);

     $font = 'fonts/arial.TTF';

    for($i=0,$y=170;$i<=9;$i++,$y=$y+65)

 {
 $rand_no1 = rand(20,50);
 $rand_no2 = rand(20,60);

 $friend_name = $final_friends[$i]["name"];

   imagettftext( $dest, 15, 0, 360, $y, $view_color, $font, "    ".$rand_no1."                                                      ".$rand_no2.""); 
    imagettftext( $dest, 18, 0, 80, $y, $name_color, $font, $friend_name); 
}




         for($i=0,$y=150;$i<=9;$i++,$y=$y+65)
     {
      $friend_pic = $final_friends[$i]["picture"];
    $friend_pic = imagecreatefromjpeg($friend_pic);

  // Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($dest, $friend_pic, 20, $y,0, 0, 50, 50, 100);
 }

  // Output and free from memory
  imagepng($dest,$image_path,0);

 ?>
```

Comment: If you got that working it'd be shut down almost immediately for policy violations due to your prefilling the 'message' parameter with text not supplied by the user

Comment: Are you sure the URLs you're passing to imagecreatefromjpeg are the correct URLs and that they're reachable from your code?

Comment: And tagging of users in composite images is also not allowed.